# Detecting when the database session gets refreshed on a Spring Boot 2 application

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to execute the following SQL statement every time the Database Session gets refreshed. I have a Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE with JPA application and a PostgreSQL Database.

```
select set_config('SOME KEY', 'SOME VALUE', false);
```

As the PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-admin.html) states the *is_local* parameter is used to indicate that this configuration value will apply just for the current transaction -*if true*- or will be attached to the session (as I require) -*if false*-

The problem is that I'm not aware when Hibernate/Hikari are refreshing the db session, so, in practice, the application start failing when it has a couple of minutes running, as you can imagine...

My approach -*that is not working yet*- is to implement a EmptyInterceptor, for that I have added a DatabaseCustomizer class to inject my **hibernate.session_factory.interceptor** properly in a way that Spring can fill out all my @Autowires

DatabaseInterceptor.class

```
@Component
public class DatabaseInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void afterTransactionBegin(Transaction tx) {

        PersistenceService pc = context.getBean(PersistenceService.class);

        try {
            pc.addPostgresConfig("SOME KEY", "SOME VALUE");
            System.out.println("Config added...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

DatabaseCustomizer.class

```
@Component
public class DatabaseCustomizer implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseInterceptor databaseInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.session_factory.interceptor", databaseInterceptor);
    }

}
```

Obviously, there is a problem with this approach because when I @Override the *afterTransactionBegin* method to start another transaction I get an Infinite loop.

I tried to look something inside that *Transaction tx* that could help to be sure that this transaction is not being generated by my own *addPostgresConfig* but there is not much on it.

Is there something else I could try to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I solve this issue on my project by applying a very different approach, instead of using set_config() and then current_setting() in a \@ColumnTransformation I have added to my \@ColumnTransformation with a text place holder that later I fill out on the onPrepareStatement() method in my Interceptor. However, I'm very interested on the original question so I'm leaving this post here, hopefully some it will get an answer.